# How to add an integer-represented column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add an integer-represented column in a pandas dataframe. For example if a have a dataframe with names and genders as the following:

[image: Input]

I would need to add a new column with an integer value depending of the gender. Expected out put would be as follows:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Gender_code']=df['Gender'].transform(lambda gender: 1 if gender=='Female' else 0)
```

Explanation: Using transform(), you can apply a function to all values of any column. Here, I applied the function defined using lambda to column 'Gender'

Comment: Performance-wise this is not a good approach since `lambda` is not vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

For just two gender you can do a comparison:

```
df['Gender_code'] = df['Gender'].eq('Female').astype(int)
```

In the general case, you can resolve to `factorize`:

```
df['Gender_code'] = df['Gender'].factorize()[0]
```